# How to make text transition over a blurred image on hover?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jajyvc?file=src/circle.css

I'm trying to make the image blur and text smoothly appear upon hover, and then when you stop hovering the text smoothly fades out and the image unblurs. I feel like I'm so close.

Do you see how in the stackblitz example the text smoothly appears on hover, but its blurred and when you stop hovering the transition effect ends too soon and the text becomes unblurred for a split second?

No matter what I set the transition time to, or change the transition properties around, it happens. I'm trying to make it look smoother and more professional. How do I get rid the blur on the text but maintain the transition in and out?

I've tried setting the blur to 0 on the text directly, but that doesn't work.

```
  #site-circle:hover #circle-title {
    -webkit-opacity: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0px);
    -ms-filter: blur(0px);
    -o-filter: blur(0px);
    filter: blur(0px);
```

Then I thought maybe the blur was "covering" it, so I set a z-index to 999 but that doesn't work either.

Idk what I'm missing or what to do? Help?

---

CODE IF DON'T WANT TO CLICK STACKBLITZ

```css
#link-container a {
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/Sd6kP7T/Screenshot-155.png);
  background-position: top;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#link-container #circle-title {
  margin-left: 47px;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #dbe8d4;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  opacity: 0;
  /* position: absolute;
            bottom: 0px; */
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#link-container:hover a {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

#link-container:hover #circle-title {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="link-container">
  <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer">
    <div id="circle-title">TEXT</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Isnt the only problem that you set blur in #wordle:hover a ? Try setting the blur top 0px.

Comment: the <a> tag is the actual image circle I want to blur on hover. The text is "#circle-title" and I DONT want it to blur, just smooth transition in and out

Answer (score 0):

You should take the `#circle-title` out of the `<a>` and position it over the image using `position: absolute;`! When blurring a parent element the children will automatically get blurred too, so in you can't really unblur your text with this html

```css
#link-container {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}

#link-container a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("https://i.ibb.co/Sd6kP7T/Screenshot-155.png");
  background-position: top;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#link-container #circle-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #dbe8d4;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
}

#link-container:hover a {
  -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px);
  -o-filter: blur(1px);
  filter: blur(1px);
  transform: scale(1.03);
}

#link-container:hover #circle-title {
  -webkit-opacity: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="link-container">
  <a href="#" rel="noopener noreferrer"></a>
  <div id="circle-title">TEXT</div>
</div>
```